# Grails Mail MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx, port: 25, response: 421

Tags: email, grails, smtp

I used the unsecured email server (not ssl).

I found that 421 is for: 421 - The service is not available and the connection will be closed.

Grails email plugin configuration:

```
grails {
mail {
    host = "xxx.xxx"
    port = 25
    username = "username"
    password = "secret"

    props = ["mail.smtp.auth": "true",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port": "25"
    ]
}}
```

And the exception I got is:

```
Error Exception in thread "Thread-34" 
| Error org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 25, response: 421. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 25, response: 421; message exception details (1) are:
| Error Failed message 1:
| Error javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 25, response: 421
| Error     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
| Error     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
| Error     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
| Error     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
| Error     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
| Error     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
| Error     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender$send$0.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:104)
| Error     at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder$sendMessage$0.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
| Error     at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:41)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor488.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1108)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```

Comment: make sure your host is valid.

Comment: I can ping my host. Are there something wrong with my Grails configuration?

Comment: Your grails configuration looks right. You should ask your host provider for the configuration for mail. Mine gave me the following for my last app. `grails {
            mail {
                host = "localhost"
                port = 25
                props = ["mail.smtp.from":"no-reply@domain.com"]
    
            }
        }` This only works in production. I used gmail configuration in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in production with my current host. You can ask your hosting provider for your configuration.

```
grails {
        mail {
            host = "localhost"
            port = 25
            props = ["mail.smtp.from":"no-reply@mydomain.com"]

        }
    }
```